# JavaScript image combobox v3.2 selected attribute

Tags: jquery-plugins, selected, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm using [JavaScript image combobox v3.2](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) plug-in , it's a drop-down list with images and I'm just trying to set selected attribute to one of the options of the drop down list using PHP , because I'm getting this value (if specific option is selected from XML file) so I have to do this in PHP 
, but it's not working as usual select

```
array ('selected' => 'selected');
```

or

```
array ('selected' => true);
```

and I couldn't find any thing on the web similar to my problem .

Had anyone tried this plug-in ?

```
$('#selectid > option:eq(1)').attr ('selected' , ?)
```